# why does MSVC 2015 takes too much space

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have an installation of visual studio 2015 (french version). The installation itself take a lot of disk space. I have only C++ compiler installed without .net, C#, web and mobile developer toolkit.

Does anybody know what is the actual reason for too much disk space requirement compared to other C/C++ compiler toolkits (GCC, Clang).

another point:
Installing a language pack for english demands 4GB of disk space. Why it requires that much space where I am installing only a different language. I mean compiler executable remains same in this case. Just the internationalization parameters needs to be changed.

Is there any technical or commercial reasons to why Visual Studio do this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The installation itself take a lot of disk space. ... Does anybody know what is the actual reason for too much disk space requirement compared to other C/C++ compiler toolkits (GCC, Clang).

Because Visual Studio installs a heck of a lot more stuff than just a compiler toolkit like GCC or Clang. For example, it includes an IDE, an interactive debugger, a bunch of libraries, the source code for all of the included libraries, profiling and other tools, etc.

If you just want the compiler toolchain and not the IDE or anything else, download the [standalone C++ build tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/02/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments/).

Or, for an earlier version of the build tools, just download the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive). (The build tools are no longer included starting with the Windows 8.1 SDK. Therefore, you'll need to get an older version, like the Windows 7 SDK.)

Comment: what about language pack only install. i had activated only C++ in vc install and language pack takes 4GB